# How to change whole UI on an ASP.NET website?

Tags: asp.net, themes

I am working on asp.net website and i want to implement themes on my site. If i select any theme then it will change whole UI not only colors. After Change it will show a new User interface. Like change in div size, width and location same for controls and same all html tag that is used in page.

I got lot of example of themes where it it changing only UI color. Can any buddy suggest me the any example where whole UI can change.

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Two suggestions spring to mind, they are separate but combined at the same time. They are [Master pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx) and [CSS](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/Overview.en.html).

Master pages would allow you to implement significantly different [HTML markup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) for the page structure while CSS allows you to implement differing attributes (size, location, colour, border, font, etc) for the markup elements.

So, if you are just looking to rearrange the elements on a page then CSS alone can help. Look at [CSS Zen Garden](http://www.csszengarden.com/) for loads of examples of what's possible.

If, however, you are looking to completely change the interface, perhaps by representing data using different controls then [Master pages](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wtxbf3hh.aspx) is probably your first stop.